# page.php not showing content

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I started developing my first WordPress theme and I'm having a problem with the `page.php` not showing content on newly created pages.
Here is my code for the `index.php` and `page.php`.

index.php:

```
    <?php 
get_header();
if(have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

<article class='post'>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content()?>
</article>

   <?php endwhile;
    else:
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';

    endif;
get_footer();
?>
```

and page.php:

```
<?php 
get_header();
if(have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

<article class='post page'>
    <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
    <?php the_content()?>
</article>

   <?php endwhile;
    else:
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';

    endif;
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Did you try `echo $post->post_content;`  instead of  `the_content()`?

Comment: this dosn't make a change, still no content displayd

Comment: "page.php not showing content on newly created pages", do you mean index.php? also index.php has nothing to do with page.php, it's related to single.php, your templates look ok to me by the way.

Comment: have you created from admin panel ?

Comment: Did you put WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php on true to show any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was't a problem at at all... I thought that every page i create from the pannel need to have the content from the posts :) that's all. Sorry for the inconvinient